# how to use $elemMatch on array specifying an upper field as part of the query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'd like to retrieve for a specific user, his chats with unread messages.

Lets say I have a simplified chat model like that :

```
{
  lastMessageAt: Date,
  participants: [
    {
      user: String(id),
      lastReadAt: Date
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve my query ?

I have tried several thing like with $elemMatch, but lastMessageAt is unknown at this level...

```
ChatDB.find({
  'participants': {
    $elemMatch: { user: '12345', lastReadAt: { $lt: '$lastMessageAt' } }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

`$elemMatch` operator will find those documents in `ChatDB` collection that have **at least 1 element** in `participants` that matches your criteria. Also my research ended with the conslusion that it is not yet possible to access other document field in `$elemMatch` operator. Anyway, if this is your goal, then you can use this query:

```
ChatDB.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "participants.user": "12345",
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          "$participants.lastReadAt",
          "$lastMessageAt"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zfh9kI7nu1G)

If you also want to filter `participants` that really matched the criteria, then you need to add a *projection* stage:

```
ChatDB.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "participants.user": "12345",
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          "$participants.lastReadAt",
          "$lastMessageAt"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      participants: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$participants",
          as: "participant",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$participant.user",
                  "12345"
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$participant.lastReadAt",
                  "$lastMessageAt"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qNk9zClknnf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway the queries you mentioned doesn't work, they retrieve the chats that have user=12345 in their participants and have at least one participant that have unread messages.
What I would like is to retrieve the chats that have user=12345 which have unread messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution witch is to use the aggregator with the $unwind operator.

```
await ChatDB.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: '$participants'
      },
      {
        $match: {
          'participants.user': '12345',
          $expr: {
            $lt: [
              '$participants.lastReadAt',
              '$lastMessageAt'
            ]
          }
        }
      }]);
```

Hope this will be usefull